# MySQL Syntax - Standard deviation for variables, not a column

Tags: mysql, function, variables, syntax

I'm trying to find the syntax to calculate the *standard deviation* for a set of variables in a stored procedure.

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
set variable1 = 5;
set variable2 = 7;
set variable3 = 8;
set variable4 = 2;

set MyStandardDeviation = StdDev(variable1, Variable2, variable3, variabl4)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select standard deviation within a row? (in SQL - or R :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985333/how-to-select-standard-deviation-within-a-row-in-sql-or-r)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `UNION ALL` to combine and produce one column temporary table,

```
set variable1 = 5;
set variable2 = 7;
set variable3 = 8;
set variable4 = 2;

set MyStandardDeviation = 
            (
                SELECT StdDev(x.Val)
                FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT variable1 As Val
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT variable2 As Val
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT variable3 As Val
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT variable4 As Val
                    ) x
            );
```