# MySQL: Standard deviation average within a table

Tags: php, mysql, standard-deviation

Here's how one of my tables are structured:

```
id | group | val1 | val2 | val3
1  | 1     | 22   | 23   | 60
2  | 1     | 40   | 60   | 80
3  | 2     | 50   | 5    | 70
4  | 2     | ...
5  | 2     | 
6  | 3     | 
...
```

In my PHP-document I'm calculating the standard deviation by using val1+val2+val3 etc. per row WHERE group equals the one I'm displaying.

Now I want to know, by using MySQL, **what the standard deviation is per row** and **the average across a group**. `(row1stddev+row2stddev+...)/n`

I've tried using subqueries, but all I can achieve is getting a single value. I think I have a lack of understanding how the the built in standard deviation functions in MySQL actually works with multiple values.

EDIT.
This is the two things I'm looking for:

```
id | group | stddev
1  | 1     | 21,65641
2  | 1     | 20
3  | 2     | 33,29164
4  | 2     | ...
5  | 2     | 
6  | 3     |
```

And average by group (average of all stddev):

group | avg_stddev
1     | 20,828205
2     | ...
3     | ...

The point of this is that I want to know in which group the difference is largest.

Comment: can u give exemple how u want it ?

Comment: This might help to get idea of possibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985333/how-to-select-standard-deviation-within-a-row-in-sql-or-r

Comment: is this right ? `21,65641` i found it `17.68238` here how to calculate http://explorable.com/calculate-standard-deviation.html

Comment: I used STDEV in Excel to calculate the results for my example here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mysql native function `STDDEV_POP` accepts only column, you have to trick it by using temporary table, that will have one column with all values (that matters to standard deviation) in a row, for that use `UNION ALL` with 3 `SELECTS`, each for one meaningful column, and group it by row id.

```sql
SELECT 
    id,
    STDDEV_POP(val) AS row_stddev 
FROM (
    SELECT id, val1 AS val FROM stdev_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, val2 AS val FROM stdev_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, val3 AS val FROM stdev_table
) tmp0
GROUP BY id
```

you can also select additional column - `group` and create another temporary table to select average from it:

```sql
SELECT 
    id_group,
    AVG(row_stddev) AS group_avg 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        id_group, 
        STDDEV_POP(val) AS row_stddev 
    FROM (
        SELECT id, id_group, val1 AS val FROM stdev_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, id_group, val2 AS val FROM stdev_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, id_group, val3 AS val FROM stdev_table
    ) tmp0
    GROUP BY id
) tmp1
GROUP BY id_group
```

Comment: Thank you. After your first block of code I got the concept :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you should create View

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT val1, val2, val3,  val1 + val2 + val 3 / 3 AS average FROM tablename;
```

and then just `SELECT * FROM view_name` to get you values.

Comment: Yes, then I have the average for a row. Here's the tricky part: How do I get the standard deviation value from the same row? AND how do I get an average of all those single standard deviation values from within a group?