# How to get standard deviation for every row?

Tags: mysql

Say, I've a table as given below:

```
id, c1, c2, c3, ..... c365, StdDeviation
1 , 3 , 7 , 1 , ..... c365, null
2 , 4 , 5 , 2 , ..... c365, null
3 , 5 , 3 , 4 , ..... c365, null
4 , 6 , 2 , 6 , ..... c365, null
5
.
.
millions
```

I would like to get the following using MySQL

```
id, c1, c2, c3, ..... c365, StdDeviation
1 , 3 , 7 , 1 , ..... c365, *standard deviation of this row*
2 , 4 , 5 , 2 , ..... c365, *standard deviation of this row*
3 , 5 , 3 , 4 , ..... c365, *standard deviation of this row*
4 , 6 , 2 , 6 , ..... c365, *standard deviation of this row*
5
.
.
millions
```

I can't use `STDDEV()` as it do works vertically. Any solution?

Comment: yes, i did, sorry, that previous question was not upto my need. Actually, i'm calculating correlation. But trying to learn to get standard deviation first :)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985333/how-to-select-standard-deviation-within-a-row-in-sql-or-r

Comment: yes, i have seen that, i have searched a lot before i posted this question. Well, in that link, the solution is the create a separate table. Is there any way without creating another table?

Answer (score 1):

Well, standard deviation is the square root of the average variance.  You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

Calculating this using the standard formula involves lots of arithmetic.  Here is the format:

```
select sqrt((pow(c1 - cavg, 2) + pow(c2 - cavg, 2) + . . .
            ) / 365
           ) as stdev
from (select t.*,
             (c1 + c2 + c3 + . . . + c365)/365 as cavg
      from yourtable t
     ) t
```

These formulas a long.  I'd recommend that you use a tool like Excel to generate them automatically.

There are alternative formulations, but they still involve summing the squares of the values and taking the square of the sum of the values -- so it doesn't simplify writing out the formula.

It is much easier to express the formula when the data is stored in a more normalized format of one row per data point.  That is what the aggregation function `std()` does.